# Script with threads working in IDLE but not by command line Ubuntu

Tags: python, multithreading

I try run simple code from "Programming Python" Mark Lutz. When I run from IDLE everything's allright. When I run from command line script doesn't work - no output, any bugs, just finished after time defined in `time.sleep()`.

How can I run this script correctly from the command line?
I'm working with Ubuntu.

```
import Queue, thread, time


    producersnumber=3
    consumersnumber=1
    msgnum=3
    dataqueue=Queue.Queue()#why double
    safeprint=thread.allocate_lock()

    def producer(no):
        for i in range(msgnum):
            p='signalfrom %s'%no
            time.sleep(1)
            dataqueue.put(p)

    def consumer(no):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                data=dataqueue.get(block=False)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
            else:
                safeprint.acquire()
                print data
                safeprint.release()
    if __name__=='__main__':
        for i in range(consumersnumber):
            thread.start_new_thread(consumer,(i,))
        for i in range(producersnumber):
            thread.start_new_thread(producer,(i,))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Idle shows more than when it's run in the console. Try adding `print` commands into your script to show the values of variables.

Comment: I expect **p** variable from producer() printed by consumer(), using Queue.put()/Queue.get()

Comment: Your code is also not the same as the code in the book

Comment: Yes I know that, You think only about difference in string from output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `time.sleep(1)`, in the last line, will kill the threads by program exit before they actually do anything (as the producer waits for a second before sending anything). Change that line to `time.sleep(10)` or diminish the values for `time.sleep()` that you have in the `producer` or `consumer`.

With `time.sleep(10)` you'll get:

```
signalfrom 1
signalfrom 0
signalfrom 2
signalfrom 1
signalfrom 0
signalfrom 2
signalfrom 1
signalfrom 0
signalfrom 2
```